# Accessing NTP at time.apple.com

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to use this simple code example to get the header from time.appple.com

Code:

```
-(void)getNTPTime{

NSString *testString = @"time.apple.com";    
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:testString]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data,
                                           NSError *connectionError) {

                            NSLog(@"Response %@ ", [response description]);
                           NSLog(@"Data %@ ", [data description]);
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError  );
                           // handle response
    }];

}
```

When using this string, I receive an error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"

If I append the URL with http://time.apple.com, then the request doesn't process. If I create the URL as http://www.time.apple.com, i receive an error the the URL does not exist. If I try http://www.apple.com I get a good data.

When I ping time.apple.com in the terminal, it's valid. When i try the other variations they are not.

Can I not use NSURLConnection on a non-http connection?

Any help appreciated

Comment: NTP does not even use TCP, it is based on UDP (port 123). I am pretty sure that you cannot use NSURLConnection.

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html: *"The recommended way to send and receive UDP packets is by combining the POSIX API and either the CFSocket or GCD APIs. ..."*

Comment: You could also have a look at https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket, which is an Objective-C wrapper for both TCP and UDP networking. Haven't used it myself, but looks promising.

Comment: There are far more examples and code snippets of creating a UDP connection and getting the ntp time in C++. Then its just a matter of creating a .mm file in Objective C to handle the data. Still couldn't have done it without your preliminary info.